# Ffmpeg show an image for multiple seconds before a video without re-encoding

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, png

I've been looking all around for this. Problem is that most google searches end up with being about creating a video from solely PNG files.
I've found this command which does the job :

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 5 -i firstimage.jpg  -t 5 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 5 -i secondimage.png -t 5 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 5 -i thirdimage.png -t 5 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i "shadowPlayVid.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0][2:0][3:0][4:0][5:0][6:0][6:1] concat=n=4:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map [v] -map [a] output.mp4 >> log_file1.txt 2>&1
```

But it seems to reencode the whole video, the input video is H.264 without CFR, but it seems to me that putting just some images before the video shouldn't take too long.

Because it ends up encoding the whole thing, this takes about 2 hours with a video of 30 minutes on a strong computer, while I feel like without encoding this should be able to be done much quicker. How do I make sure it doesn't re-encode while maintaining every image showing for 5 seconds first?

Comment: You can try encoding the image alone into a short video using the same encoding options as for the other video. And then concatenate the two videos together.

Comment: You are using the concat filter. Any filter use means ffmpeg will re-encode. As said above, generate a combined video with the rest of the assets, then use the concat **demuxer** to combine the two, while specifying `-c copy`

Comment: @Mulvya , I'll try this and get back to you, thanks alot!

Comment: @Mulvya , doing this for some odd reason slows down the video exactly 4x  
Code I tried : 
`ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 60 -r 60 -t 5 -i sample-out3.jpg  -t 5 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -c:v libx264 playervid.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i vidlist.txt -c copy output.mp4`  
vidlist contains :  
file 'playervid.mp4'  
file 'playVideo.mp4'
I can't figure out why, the video is not CFR tho, but mostly 60fps

Comment: Sounds like a timebase difference. Post ffprobe output for the game video and your generated one.

Comment: @Mulvya , not sure where you're supposed to upload it on stackoverflow, sorry if this breaks etiquette but here's a pastebin : http://pastebin.com/t82QG9PS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate your `playervid.mp4` via

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -framerate 60 -t 5 -i sample-out3.jpg -f lavfi -t 5 -i aevalsrc=0 -vf settb=1/60000 -video_track_timescale 60000 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p playervid.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped alot , sped up the process about 100 times, only had some problems with audio being desynced and mono, so had to change aevalsrc=0 to "aevalsrc=0|0:s=48000" , I'm not sure if I need to do something about the bitrate though

Comment: No, bitrate can be left alone.